# Synonym proposal: [jetpack] -> [firefox-addon-sdk]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Jetpack is the old name of Mozilla's Add-on SDK. We currently have two tags meaning the same thing:

- [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack) **× 61**
- [firefox-addon-sdk](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk) **× 175**

All questions in these tags refer to the Add-on SDK so I would suggest that [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack) is made a synonym of [firefox-addon-sdk](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk). Unfortunately, so far there are only four users who could theoretically vote on my synonym proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "jetpack" is too generic to be a synonym for anything. (For one thing, it's the name of a collection of plugins for WordPress from Automattic.)

Tag cleanup, yes; tag synonym, no.

Comment: After going through the questions tagged "jetpack" again - there are indeed two questions (both from 2010) not referring to Firefox add-ons but rather to the Jetpack theme for Silverlight. But the overwhelming majority of Jetpack questions still refers to Firefox (currently 59, there used to be more however).